# Visual Studio Code Extension: HTML Preview; External CSS it's not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling for hours now why the HTML Preview is not working, I search on Google even on this site and nothing helped, so that's why I post this question.

[Preview Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/500gE.png)

I tried to make a separate CSS file and also embedded CSS style into the page.

Here is my code

Head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Ana Sayfa</title>
```

Body

```
 <div id="sayfa">
    <header>
        <div id="banner">
            Banner
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            Logo
        </div>
        <div id="sosyalmedya">
            Sosyal Medya
            <div class="face"></div>
            <div class="twit"></div>
            <div class="insta"></div>
        </div>

    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="ana-menu">
            Ana Menü
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div id="icerik">
            İçerik
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <div id="yan-menu">
            Yan Menü
        </div>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <div id="alt-menu">
            Alt Menü
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: is the css file in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: yes, both files are in the same folder.

Comment: ok but why do you have the head split from the body? and no document container?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you should look at.

First you probably need to wrap your head and body in a document to have a full valid html document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

 </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

You also want to close your single tags in the head. Most of the time we open and close tag like this.

```
<div></div>
```

Single Tags, like an image will be represented as one tag tag is closing within itself.

```
<img attr="..." />
```

The forward slash is closing that single tag. Your Meta tags are not closed.

They should be.

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I'm not sure this will fix your issue because but it will get you closer to a standard html document.